# Djikstra's algorithm to compute shortest paths using at least k edges

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

I have a graph `G = (V, E)` where each edge is bidirectional with positive weight. I want to find the shortest path from vertex `s` to vertex `t` using *at least* `k` edges but less than 20. No vertex may be repeated in a path.

I am aware of this problem: [Dijkstra's algorithm to compute shortest paths using k edges?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53192/dijkstras-algorithm-to-compute-shortest-paths-using-k-edges)

That problem wants to find the shortest paths using *at most* `k` edges.

My current idea is to create the product graph via `V' = V x {0, 1, 2, ..., 20}` and then ignore any shortest paths from `(s, 0)` to `(t, n)` where `n < k`.  However, because the product construction essentially duplicates nodes, I am not aware of a way to ignore duplicate vertices in the path-finding algorithm.

P.S. If `k` were very large, say, `k = |V|`, wouldn't this be the Hamiltonian path problem and therefore NP-complete?

Comment: For the PS: yes, it does include Hamiltonian Path Problem as a subproblem.

Comment: @John Dvorak the linked problem gave a worst case complexity of (⋅(||+||)lg|) and it includes the Hamiltonian Path Problem if k = |V| and there are no paths for k less than this.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: @csquestions, if you are not allowed cycles, then this is NP-complete. See [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/102558/68251), specifically the first and last bullet point. Also see last paragraph of [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/102596/68251) to that question.

Comment: if you allow cycles, then you can either replicate the graph $k$ times, or apply some dynamic programming approach. Since you don't, it's NP-complete

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your problem is NP Complete, since you require that no vertex will be visited twice.

Consider we had a polynomial time solution for some $k$. For clarification; given an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ and two vertices $s,t$, we can find a shortest path from $s$ to $t$ of length $\geq k$ in polynomial time. Then, by extension we can solve in polynomial time for $k=n-1$ and thus find a path that visits eeach vertex in $V$ exactly once. In other words, we can "solve" Hamiltonian Path.

If you know in advance that $k \leq 20$ then you can exhaustive search all paths of length at most 20, and therefore solve for small $k$.

An exhaustive search, at worst, is to search every vertex order starting from $s$ that ends in $t$ (corresponding to existing edges), so in total you will search:
 $$(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)...(n-20) = O(n^{20})$$